# Cmd copy files with filename length longer than 3 characters

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to ask you. How, I can copy all files with filename longer than 3 characters. I need to write it in batch. I don't know, it is makeable, but I'm asking.

Comment: You've posted your question to a site which helps you to fix a specific replicable issue with your provided code. It appears that you should have posted it elsewhere, perhaps [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). Please delete it, or post the code you've written to perform the task and explain how it fails to work as intended, thank you.

Comment: Which code? Do you readed my question?

Comment: Did you read my comment? This site is for helping you to fix a problem in your code, without code your question is about general programming and therefore off topic here.

Comment: I need a biggest than 3 from selected directory. :(

Comment: what is a biggest than 3?? Can you please edit your question and show examples of what you want to do?

Comment: The name of file. In directory can be many files, thats my problem.

Comment: but what do you want? you need to show us, we cannot guess what you want.

Comment: Do you want to copy all files that have more than 3 characters? so let's say you have `123.txt`, `12.txt` and `1234.txt` you want to copy only `1234.txt`?

Comment: So ok. I thinking about simplest method, but if it is only way. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following complete [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) should copy all accessible files in the current directory which have a base name of at least four characters, *(extensions, existing or otherwise, are disregarded)*. The files will be copied to a directory named `copied` in the current directory, *(this will be created if it doesn't already exist)*.

```bat
@Set "SPO=%__CD__:~2%"
@For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%# In ('^""%__APPDIR__%wbem\WMIC.exe" DataFile Where "Drive='%__CD__:~,2%' And Path='%SPO:\=\\%' And FileName Like '____%%'" Get Name /Format:List 2^>NUL^"')Do @For /F Tokens^=* %%A In ("%%$")Do @"%__APPDIR__%xcopy.exe" "%%A" "%__CD__%copied\" /QHRKY>NUL 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@echo off

::--------------------------------------
set "source_folder=C:\source\"
set "dest_folder=.\testfolder\"
::--------------------------------------

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in ("%source_folder%\*") do (
  set "filename=%%~nxa"
  rem if you don't want to count the extention too use  set "filename=%%~na"
  call ::strlen filename len
  if !len! GTR 3 (
    copy "%%~fa" "%dest_folder%" /y
  )
)



exit /b %errorlevel%

:strlen  StrVar  [RtnVar]
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "s=#!%~1!"
  set "len=0"
  for %%N in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if "!s:~%%N,1!" neq "" (
      set /a "len+=%%N"
      set "s=!s:~%%N!"
    )
  )
  endlocal&if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%len%) else echo %len%
exit /b
```

You'll need to change the paths in the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the name for a 4th character, if it has one, then it is more than 3 characters, if not, it is 3 or less. This example only `echos` the result, not actually copy it:

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for %%a in (*) do (
       set "fname=%%~na"
       if "!fname:~3,1!" == "" (
         echo "%%~a" 3 or less chars
       ) else (
         echo "%%~a" more than 3 chars
     )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

filename (without extension) 3 or more characters:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('where /r . "???*.*"') do @echo %~nxa
```

(Command line syntax. For use within a batch file, use `%%a` and `%%~nxa`)

`Where` uses a different definition of the wildcard `?` ("exactly one char").
The `/r` switch defines a start folder for recursive search (the current working folder (`.`) here).
`where /r` returns the full path by default.

Answer (score 0):

This work to me:

Replace using your target path for source files/destiny folder in this commands:

> - **`cd /d "D:\FolderX\"`**
> - **`"%temp%\Target_DirX\"`**
>
>   ---

1) go to drive and folder where are your files by cd /d

2) use 1st to loop to list files by dir cmd, excluding directory /a: -d

3) use 2nd for loop, to count the string in the filename <strike>d:\folder\</strike> **name_file_only** <strike>.docx</strike>

4) use if to check if file name is greater than 3, copy files to destination if true:

---

```bat
@echo off && cd /d "D:\FolderX\"

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:-d ".\*.*"')do for /f %%C in ('
cmd /u/c set /p "'="%%~ni""^<nul^|find /v /c "^^"')do if %%~C gtr 3 (
copy "%%~fi" "%temp%\Target_DirX\") else echo= %%~nxi less/equal 3^!!
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can *ALMOST* do this directly, no `for` loop or other complex methods needed, just simple file `globs`. **

However because `?` equals "any 0 or 1 characters", not "any one character" for most of the windows commands.  So you could easily select any file up to x characters straight up.

SO the following would work if you want to copy and then delete any files that are not long enough after the fact without any loops or other process needed.

On the CLI:

```
COPY "C:\Source\folder\path\*.*" "C:\Dst\folder\path\"
DEL /F /Q "C:\Dst\folder\path\???.*"
```

A bit more fluff here in a batch file as you might want to do more with it:

```
@(SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_Src_Path=C:\Source\folder\path"
  SET "_Dst_Path="C:\Dst\folder\path"
  SET "_Src_FileGlob=*.*"
  SET "_Dst_FileGlob=???.*"
)

COPY "%_Src_Path%\%_Src_FileGlob%" "%_Dst_Path%\"
DEL /F /Q "%_Dst_Path%\%_Dst_FileGlob%"
```

You can use `Robocopy`/`Move`/`Dir`/`Type`/`Find`/`FindStr`/`FOR` loops/etc with a `File glob` as you like.

`File Globs` are **NOT** `regex` but can still offer quite a lot of flexibility to empower simple commands to accomplish things such as in your request without having to write any complex scripting.

** On Windows you are limited to Files for globs, and you can only use static characters, and `?` for "Any zero or one Characters" (This IS actually the Regex equivalent of `?`) `*`  for "any Character any number of times"

To do this so that you don't copy any files you don't want and have to delete them after (which is definitely less efficient although as above simple to achieve, you can instead do the following with a loop at the CLI:

CLI as a Single line (easy to up arrow and run again:

```
for /F "Tokens=*" %_ IN ('FOR %A IN (C:\Source\folder\path\???.*^) DO @ECHO.%A ^|FindStr /R /C:"^.*\\[^\\][^\\][^\\][^\\][^\\]*$"') DO ( COPY "%_" "C:\Dst\folder\path\" )
```

CLI as multi-line (Easier to read, can still just be pasted in):

```
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %_ IN ('
  FOR %A IN (
    C:\Source\folder\path\???.*
  ^) DO @ECHO.%A ^|FindStr /R /C:"^.*\\[^\\][^\\][^\\][^\\][^\\]*$"
') DO ( COPY "%_" "C:\Dst\folder\path\" )
```

A bit more fluff here in a batch file as you might want to do more with it:

```
@(SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_Src_Path=C:\Source\folder\path"
  SET "_Dst_Path="C:\Dst\folder\path"
  SET "_Src_FileGlob=???*.*"
  SET "_Dst_FileGlob=???.*"
)

FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%_ IN ('
  FOR %%A IN (
    C:\Source\folder\path\???.*
  ^) DO ECHO.%%A ^|FindStr /R /C:"^.*\\[^\\][^\\][^\\][^\\][^\\]*$"
') DO ( COPY "%%_" "C:\Dst\folder\path\" )
```

additionally as was pointed out by Compo it's only Where which does fit the expected behavior:

At the CLI:

```
for /F "Tokens=*" %_ IN ('WHERE "C:\Source\folder\path:????.*"') DO ( COPY "%_" "C:\Dst\folder\path\" )
```

In a simple Script:

```
@(SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_Src_Path=C:\Source\folder\path"
  SET "_Dst_Path="C:\Dst\folder\path"
  SET "_Src_FileGlob=????*.*"
)

for /F "Tokens=*" %_ IN ('
  WHERE "%_Src_Path%:%_Src_FileGlob%"
') DO ( COPY "%_" "%_Dst_Path%\" )
```

Comment: Ben, your [tag:copy] 'Glob', will match files named `1.c` and `a.h` which don't fulfill the criteria, *even with the extension included!*

Comment: Sadly the wildcard `?` means "zero or one character" (except with the `where` command)

Comment: @Compo, and @Stephan, Nice I hadn't noticed in previous usages of this that it was 0 or 1 character so `?` = actual regex `?` NOT Regex `.` while `*` still sands as .`*` Thanks for the note I've amended it.